# osgeo ogr layer fieds - have become invisible

Tags: python, postgresql, osgeo

We have e python script, using osgeo, that accesses a PostgreSQL database for GIS data. The script have unexpected stopped working, and I have been able to boil it down to:
.GetFieldCount() returns 0, though fields do exist.

I can reproduce the error via this script, which is a modified version of the online-help.

```
from osgeo import ogr
import sys

databaseServer = "postgrestest1"
port = "5433" # <-- I know default is 5432, bu this server uses 5433
databaseName = "pgv_2017"
databaseUser = "myname"
databasePW = "mypassw"
connString = "PG: host=%s port=%s dbname=%s user=%s password=%s"    %(databaseServer,port,databaseName,databaseUser,databasePW)

lyr_name = "k.jis"


def GetPGLayerFields( lyr_name ):
    conn = ogr.Open(connString)
    print "conn:", conn

    lyr = conn.GetLayer( lyr_name )
    print "lyr:", lyr

    lyrDefn = lyr.GetLayerDefn()
    print "lyrDefn:", lyrDefn

    num_flds = lyrDefn.GetFieldCount()
    print "num_flds:", num_flds

    for i in range(num_flds):
        print lyrDefn.GetFieldDefn( i ).GetName()

    conn.Destroy()


if __name__ == '__main__':

    GetPGLayerFields( lyr_name )
```

The output looks like this:

```
C:\Martin\Work>python test_pg_connect.py
conn: <osgeo.ogr.DataSource; proxy of <Swig Object of type 'OGRDataSourceShadow *' at 0x00000000021C0720> >
lyr: <osgeo.ogr.Layer; proxy of <Swig Object of type 'OGRLayerShadow *' at 0x00000000021C0660> >
lyrDefn: <osgeo.ogr.FeatureDefn; proxy of <Swig Object of type 'OGRFeatureDefnShadow *' at 0x0000000004541030> >
num_flds: 0

C:\Martin\Work>
```

So the program can see the table, but thinks it has no fields?

But as seen below, the same table seen in the db (with the same user credentials) has 2 fields, 'jis_id' and 'geom'.

Can anybody suggest a way to access these fields from python/osgeo?

/Martin

[image: Same data viewed from pgadmin]

Comment: I believe that `layerDefinition.GetFieldCount()` returns the number of user defined fields and because your table has only fid and geometry the number is zero which is correct.

Comment: Thanks for your instructive replies, they are valuable help. Can any body suggest a way to list and/or access the other fields, including the two I have in my table?

Comment: See the answer by @Pablo.

Comment: the 'jis_id' _is_ a user defined field, we made it on purpose with an SQL script. It's a foreign key to another db table.

Comment: Add SQL for CREATE TABLE... and one INSER INTO... and maybe somebody will make a test with their own PostGIS.

Answer (score 2):

The feature ID and the geometry are "special" fields and you need to use specific methods to access them.

In order to access the feature ID (jis_id) use `feature.GetFID()`, for example (Python 2.7):

```
layer.ResetReading()
for feature in layer:
    print feature.GetFID()
```

To access the geometry (geom), use `feature.GetGeometryRef()`, it returns a `Geometry` object. Then you can use for example `geometry.ExportToWkt()` or any other [geometry method](http://gdal.org/python/osgeo.ogr.Geometry-class.html).

Comment: Hi @Pablo. Your script runs fine, but the FID that it returns is not the same number as the 'jis_id' I'm looking for. Apparently it is some (internal?) integer id number in the db.